# Unable to get share menu to work with PDF data using Mac Catalyst

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst

I am attempting to use a UIActivityViewController to create a share menu using PDF data using the code below. (The type is 'Data', I also attempted NSData to no avail):

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [documentData],
            applicationActivities: nil)
```

It works fine on iPhone and iPad but when running on macOS I only get "More..."

[image: More... screenshot]

By comparison here's how the exact same file behaves on iOS:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the data to a file and share the URL of that file.

```swift
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("file.pdf")
try? pdfData.write(to: fileURL)

let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```